# How can I enhance the speed of docker site

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-machine

I have site running on a docker container here is my compose file it is quite basic

```
version: '3'

services:
  apache:
    image: httpd:latest
    networks:
      vlan-ecm:
        ipv4_address: 172.16.21.100
    ports:
      - "8080:80"  # Correct indentation here
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./html:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs
networks:
  vlan-ecm:
    external: true
```

however I was wondering if there is anything I can do to enhance the loading speed of my site considering it takes ages to load. Would it be the lack of resources on my VM? what could maybe help make it load fast?

Comment: I do not belive you are thinking of this correctly....Docker is an environment to execute your App. Your issues with load speed are likely 100% due to your app, not Docker.

Comment: What is your CPU and RAM in your VM? Did you try to run your app without Docker? Sometimes Docker works very slowly especially when CPU and RAM are not enough.

Comment: While you could check the network tab of your browser to see if there are significant waiting times, it also matters a lot what that "site" actually is. Passive HTML-CSS-JS content? Or is there something that's supposed to run on the server side?